# Material3 Color Harmonization in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material-you, material3

While using the view-based system, we can harmonize a color using the below code.

```kotlin
MaterialColors.harmonizeWithPrimary(context, colorToHarmonize)
```

In a project that is fully migrated to Jetpack Compose and all the color values are stored in the `Color.kt` file, how do you apply harmonization to color at runtime?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @ShadeToD Nope :(

Comment: I was able to find a codelab about this topic, but it uses XML views.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/harmonize-color-android-views#0

Comment: @ShadeToD Yes, I also came across this concept through this codelab but wasn't able to find the same for Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method

```
MaterialColors.harmonize(colorToHarmonize, colorToHarmonizeWith)
```

And harmonize your custom color with the *primaryColor* from the dynamic color scheme

```
MaterialColors.harmonize(customColor.toArgb(), MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary.toArgb())
```

If you want to go the extra step you can provide the harmonized value(s) through *CompositionLocalProvider* to provide it down the composition, to match the way dynamic colors are provided by *MaterialTheme.colorScheme*.

I explored the issue a little more in this project: https://github.com/acolombo25/harmonized-colors-compose